# ignore csv column python/django

Tags: python, django, csv

I am importing a csv into my Django web app and `get_or_create`-ing new objects per row. However, I would like to skip a row if one of its columns does not contain one of a few approved phone numbers.

Code below, what can I add to achieve the desired result?

```
csv_file = request.FILES['file']

if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
    message.error(request, 'this is not a csv file')

data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')

io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    _, created = Call.objects.get_or_create(
        name=column[0],
        phone_number=column[1],

        etc...

    )
context = {}
```

Comment: I think `csv.reader` gives you rows not columns. Add a conditional before calling `get_org_create` based on the row value at the column index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it should be `row` not `column`. Secondly (original question), your can make a function to validate phone number and use `continue` to skip if it is not valid. say that validation function is `is_valid_phone` and returns `bool`.

```
for row in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    if not is_valid_phone(row[1]):
        continue
    # rest of code.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! column worked for me (I guess just because it is a name variable), but I changed it to row and used your suggestion; worked like a charm :)